# Telegram Laravel Bot Reply

Tags: php, laravel, telegram-bot

I'm pretty new to laravel and Telegram API and I want to develop a bot that can reply your input messages.

For now I can send messages when I refresh a route, but I would like it to send a message and reply once your start a conversation with him.

I'm using this sdk: https://telegram-bot-sdk.readme.io/docs

and so far I managed to call the send message method:

```
class TelegramController extends Controller {
    public function index(){
    
        $chatID = 'xxxxxxx';

        Telegram::sendMessage([
            'chat_id' => $chatID,
            'text' => '[▼皿▼]'
        ]);;
    
    
    }
}
```

How can I add some sort of listener that can reply to user input?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The way I've done this is by using a [WebHook](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#setwebhook).

Comment: I thought about that, but I'm doing this in my local machine so webhooks only work on servers.

Comment: I see. I am not sure how you can do this from your computer. Good luck.

Comment: Use [ngrok](https://ngrok.com)

Answer (score 0):

At first, you should add the route in `routes/web.php`, like this:

```php
Route::post('/bot_webhook', 'TelegramController@index')->middleware('api');
```

And you should get update improve `TelegramController` like this:

```php
class TelegramController extends Controller {
    public function index(){
        $update = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));

        # I'm not sure what library do you use, but it should work if it was like this
        Telegram::sendMessage([
            'chat_id' => $update->message->chat->id,
            'text' => '[▼皿▼]'
        ]);;
    }
}
```